# Luhn algorithm in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

When I have a number in my list that is greater than 9 I want to separate the
digits and add them to the running sum.

The code I have is giving me and error in my `sum-list` definition.

```
(define sum-list (lst) 
  (if (null lst)
      0
      (if (>9 car lst?) 
          (cons ((mod (car lst) 10)) + (* (remainder (/car lst 10) 10))))
      (if (>9 cdr lst?)
          (cons ((mod (cdr lst)10)) + (* (remainder (/cdr lst 10) 10)))) 
  (+ (car lst) (sum-list (cdr lst)))))
```

I am getting an error"Expected only one expression after the name sum-list but found one extra part.

Comment: This does not look like Scheme code. What book are you reading?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this now in *mit-scheme*.  I split the problem in 2 subproblems -- to conver the number to the list of digits and then to sum the digits in the resulting list.

```
(define n->l
  (lambda (n return)
    ((lambda (s) (s s n return))
     (lambda (s n col)
       (if (zero? n)
           (col '())
           (s s
              (quotient n 10)
              (lambda (rest)
                (col (cons (remainder n 10) rest)))))))))

(define sum-digits
  (lambda (n)
    (n->l n (lambda (l) (fold-left + 0 l)))))

(sum-digits 100)
(sum-digits 123)
```

Comment: `(fold + 0 (unfold zero? (cut remainder <> 10) (cut quotient <> 10) 1337)) ; ==> 14`

Comment: @Sylwester thanks.  I had forgotten to specify mit-scheme.

Comment: My one-liner works in mit-scheme as well, requires only SRFI-26 since MIT ships with SRFI-1.